# Powershell Store Variables into Variable does not work

Tags: powershell, variables, echo

I need some help with Powershell, i hope somebody can help.

I want to store multiple Variables into one single variable.

Here is my code:

```
$Content = @"
$Var1 = "1"
$Var2 = "2"
$Var3 = "3"
"@   

echo $Content
```

And thats my output:

```
echo $Content
 = "1"
 = "2"
 = "3"
```

It should look like this:

```
$Var1 = "1", etc...
```

But every variable gets removed. I don't know why. Could somebody please explain this? Do i need to store them into something like an object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Everything with `$` in the beginning is interpreted as a variable name in powershell. You have to escape the `$` if you want that inside a string. So use ``$ or instead of the double quotas (") the single (') one. --> `'@$Var = "1"'@'`

Comment: if you replace the double quotes with single quotes, then PoSh will NOT try to expand your $Vars. try `'$Var'` and `"$Var"` when there is nothing in the variable to display ... [*grin*] please take a look at >>> `about_Quoting_Rules` <<<

Comment: Good to know Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest fix for your situation is to switch to a single-quoted here-string.

```
$Content = @'
$Var1 = "1"
$Var2 = "2"
$Var3 = "3"
'@
```

---

In general, double quotes around a string instruct PowerShell to interpolate. Single quotes around a string tells PowerShell to treat the content as a literal string. This also applies to here-strings (`@""@` and `@''@`).

```
# Double Quotes

$string = "my string"
"$string"
my string

@"
$string
"@
my string

# Single Quotes

'$string'
$string

@'
$string
'@
$string
```

When interpolation happens, variables are expanded and evaluated. A variable is identified starting with the `$` character until an illegal character for a variable name is read. Notice in the example below, how the variable interpolation stops at the `.`.

```
"$string.length"
my string.length
```

---

You can use escape characters or other operators to control interpolation within double quoted strings. The subexpression operator `$()` allows an expression to be evaluated before it is converted into a string.

```
"$($string.length)"
9
```

The backtick character is the PowerShell escape character. It can be used to escape `$` when you don't want it to be treated as a variable.

```
"`$string"
$string
```

---

Mixing quotes can create certain gotchas. ***If you surround your string with single quotes,*** ***everything inside will be a literal string*** regardless of using escape characters or subexpressions.

```
'"$($string.length)"'
"$($string.length)"

'"`$string"'
"`$string"
```

Surrounding your string with double quotes with inside single quotes will just treat the inside single quotes literally because the outer quotes determine how the string will be interpreted.

```
"'$string'"
'my string'
```

Using multiple single quote pairs or double quote pairs requires special treatment. In this unique situation for double quotes, you can use the backtick escape or a two `"` to print a single `"`.

```
"""$string"""
"my string"

"`"$string`""
"my string"
```

For multiple single quotes, you must use two `'` because a backtick will be treated literally and not tell PowerShell to escape anything.

```
'''$string'''
'$string'
```

---

Please reference [About_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6) for official documentation.